# Print something after return

Tags: c

I write a Longest common Subsequence code and want to print the longest one using recursive.

If I put the `printf` before return, the result would print answer reversely ->"UAJM".

So I put the `printf` after the return.

However, the output is empty.I expect it could print the character in order ->"MJAU".

thanks a lot!

---------update---------

Oh I got it! After return, it immediately exits the function and no more code will be run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int map[20][20];
int maxlen;
int max(int a,int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}
void LCS(char* X,char* Y,int m,int n)
{
    if(!m||!n)
        return ;
    if(X[m-1]==Y[n-1])
    {
        return LCS(X,Y,m-1,n-1);
        printf("%c",X[m-1]);
    }
    if(map[m-1][n]>map[m][n-1])
        return  LCS(X,Y,m-1,n);
    else
        return  LCS(X,Y,m,n-1);

}
void LCSlength(char* X,char* Y)
{
    int len1=strlen(X),len2=strlen(Y);

    for(int i=1;i<=len1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=len2;j++)
        {
            if(X[i-1]==Y[j-1])
            {
                map[i][j]=map[i-1][j-1]+1;
            }
            else
                map[i][j]=max(map[i][j-1],map[i-1][j]);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *X = "XMJYAUZ", *Y = "MZJAWXU";
    int m=strlen(X),n=strlen(Y);
    LCSlength(X, Y);
    LCS(X, Y, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you `printf` after `return`?  You should get a warning that this line of code will never execute.

Comment: But I think the after recursive it can print out. is it wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect a function to do anything at all after you've returned from it? (A recursive function works in exactly the same way as a non-recursive function.)

Comment: Read about what `return` does. It immediately exits the function and no more code will be run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once a `return` statement is encountered, the function returns immediately from that point.  No further statements after the `return` are executed.

Just because you're using recursion that doesn't mean you need to return immediately on the recursive call.  What you need here is to first make the recursive call, then print, then return.

```
if(X[m-1]==Y[n-1])
{
    LCS(X,Y,m-1,n-1);
    printf("%c",X[m-1]);
    return;
}
if(map[m-1][n]>map[m][n-1])
    LCS(X,Y,m-1,n);
else
    LCS(X,Y,m,n-1);
```

Also, note that since the function's return type is `void` that you can't specify a return value in a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4):

`return` literally exits the function, possibly returning a value to the caller. Nothing executes in the function after it is reached.

For a `void` return, you can just put the return on a later line:

```
LCS(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1);
printf("%c", X[m - 1]);
return;
```

If your function does return something (say an `int`), you could store it in a temporary variable, do your thing, then return;

```
int val = LCS(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1);
printf("%c", X[m - 1]);
return val;
```

Answer (score -2):

Late to the party. You cannot put anything after the return statement. If you really really want it, you might emulate the behaviour. You can achieve it with macro programming.

```
#define RETURN(x, y) { \
    printf("%c", (y)); \
    return (x); \
}
```

Usage:

```
if(X[m-1]==Y[n-1]) {
    RETURN(LCS(X,Y,m-1,n-1), X[m-1]);
}
```

If you are really into it, you can create a generic version allowing for side effects on `y` from `x`:

```
#define RETURN(type, x, y) { \
    type result = (x); \
    printf("%c", (y)); \
    return (result); \
}
```

Finally, you want to print something else, you can achieve it with this macro (macro can be further improved via P99, if you really want):

```
#define RETURN(type, x, format, ...) { \
    type result = (x); \
    printf(format, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
    return (result); \
}
```

Comment: to the downvoter: I would like an explanation to surely improve my answer. Is it maybe because the solution implies masking standard C statements with the evilness that is macro programming?

Comment: NMDV, but that would be my guess.

Comment: IMHO macros cause more problems than they are worth

Comment: While I can agree that macros can indeed lead to great problem (looking at you, mantenability!) I think that they can be great tools for solving some missing features of `C`. Regarding the `return` statement issue, personally I would never do it. But what if you need to do the same thing throughout several functions? Here macros can really save you a lot of pain while still satisfying DRY principle. Then again, in wrong hands macros lead to certain failure.